# check if a bit or a package is sent correctly

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a program that checks if a bit in a package is

corrupted or not but I can't get the right logic. This is the code:

```
// a method to determine if a bit a incorrect or not with 

//probability p that a bit is not correct in other words the 

//probability of this method returning false is (p)

public static boolean bitOK(double p) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (rnd.nextDouble() < p){
        return false;
        }
        else {
        return true;
        }
}
```

```
// this is the method that's going to check if all the bits are okey using the above method. 
public static boolean packetOK(int size, double p){
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) // size is the number of bits {
            if (bitOK(p)) {
                return true; 
            }
        }
        return false; 
            
    }
```

can anyone explain to me why I'm not thinking right.
thank you

Comment: I don't quite get this. Is this a kind of simulation? `bitOK(p)` for sure isn't checking any bit value if all it takes is a probability. Can you explain what a "package" is here? Is it just a string of bits? And how would you check if a bit has the correct value or not? There are some algorithms to check if _any_ bit is corrupted e.g. by using checksums and there may be some that can tell you which bit it is but can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve - ideally with some examples?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of input information, and the output results, and explain what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: It's not checking for a value it's checking if a bit is sent without damage by comparing the probability to generated random number. And then the second method if checking for en entire package by checking if every bit is ok. what I mean by a package is a specific number of bits. say 100 bits for example

Comment: Let's say the probability of a bit is wrong p = 0,01. we generate a random number between 0 and 1 call it n and compare with p. if n < p then the bit it corrupted. else bit ok.